# php mail() sendmail, masquerade as any domain?

Tags: php, dns, sendmail

I'm running a lamp server on which i'm using the php `mail()` function to send mail from the current domain (using `$username`@`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` as the source address). I'm using many domains on the same server, and I need the email to come from the correct domain.

Right now I'm using masquerade for a single domain:

```
dnl # Masquerading options
FEATURE(`always_add_domain')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`srv.domain.org')dnl
FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
```

This works fine for this domain, but no other.

How can I set the from-field in php to whatever I want? Right now all email are sent from the same domain, no matter what domain i set in php.

EDIT:

All domain names are CNAME records, pointing to one A record, which points to the server. Every email is using that A record domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `from` address in the headers, however, beware that a lot of email clients will mark the emails as spam if the from address and the server domain don't match up.

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com'; // other headers

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

As shown in the [PHPDocs for `mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: That's what I'm doing: `$headers = "From: " . $from . "@" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

but it replaces the domain so every email comes from the same domain, no matter the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. I included `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in the content of the email just to be sure, and it differs.

Comment: also, the domain is a CNAME, that points to an A record which points to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up, installed postfix, configured it to use a smtp relay, and everything works as expected.

5 minutes, "plug'n'play".